# Google Map Not Showing Up Ionic2

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic2

I've followed the tutorial below successfully.  However when I add navigation in multiple pages the map stops loading.  It will only load if I set it as the root page.

https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/

I've tried a number of suggestions on the following form but without any success.  It **does** work in the browser but does not work when I launch it in an android emulator.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-dont-work/55637/29

This is my page ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap(){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: can you put some log before 'new google.maps.Map' to ensure it all gets called till there?

Comment: 'ionViewLoaded' is no longer a valid lifecycle event. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events. But that should not be your problem as you say it works in Browser. you must be on older version

Comment: Version 2.0.0-rc.5

Comment: Fixed.  Actually using ngOnInit.

Comment: It's not getting to the new maps.  I placed an alert prior.

Comment: However if I add an alert() prior to the geolocation call it fires.